# Confusion around Typescript type `in` operator

Tags: typescript

The [following code](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html):

```
// This makes sense
type simpleKeys = 'a' | 'b';
let anObject: { 
    [index in simpleKeys]: string;
} = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};
anObject.a;  // 'a'

// This doesn't make sense, how does `T` have many types?  It is only
// a subtype of type `string`... or is the act of invoking the function
// with many strings allowing the compiler to infer that `T` is of
// type "AA" | "BB"?
function strEnum<T extends string>(o: Array<T>): {[K in T]: K} {
  return o.reduce((res, key) => {
    res[key] = key;
    return res;
  }, Object.create(null));
}

const LABELS = strEnum(['AA', 'BB']);

type LABEL = keyof typeof LABELS;
```

I understand that `T` is a subtype of `string` so I was expecting the type system to somehow iterate over the members of `o` which are an array of `T`s.  Something like `[K in o]: K;` but I know that doesn't make sense for a compile time static analysis.  Could anyone point me to a resource to understand how to "think in types" a bit better please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// This doesn't make sense, how does `T` have many types?  It is only
// a subtype of type `string`... or is the act of invoking the function
// with many strings allowing the compiler to infer that `T` is of
// type "AA" | "BB"?
```

> or is the act of invoking the function with many strings allowing the compiler to infer that `T` is of type "AA" | "BB"?

You already know how to think in types, you just don't trust yourself yet.  This is precisely what is happening.  Simply replace "many strings" with "many literal string subtypes", since from the type system's perspective that's what's going on when you invoke `strEnum(['AA', 'BB'])`.

```
strEnum(['AA', 'BB'])
// is the same as
strEnum(['AA', 'BB'] as ['AA', 'BB']);
// or, to put it another way
strEnum(['AA' as 'AA', 'BB' as 'BB']);
// or, a third way
strEnum<'AA' | 'BB'>(['AA', 'BB']);
```